# KNN gridsearch tuning

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, grid-search

I am trying to tune my KNN model by using the following syntax

```
params = [{
    'knn_n_neighbors': [3, 5, 7, 9, 12,15,17],
    'knn_weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],
    \
    'knn_metric': ['euclidean', 'manhattan']}]

gs=GridSearchCV(KNN_model,param_grid=params, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
```

When I run this-

```
gs_result=gs.fit(X_knn_train, y_knn_train)
```

I get the error-

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter knn_metric for estimator KNeighborsClassifier(). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

What am I doing wrong? can someone tell me what parameters I am not using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your `params` dictionary with the following key names:

```
params = [{
    'n_neighbors': [3, 5, 7, 9, 12,15,17],
    'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],
    \
    'metric': ['euclidean', 'manhattan']}]
```

Comment: Ok, so param names have to be written in particular way. Thanks

Comment: In the same way that .fit() expects them in the kwargs parameters, indeed.